# Docker mount namespace to share between containers

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How the mount namespace using container's id is utilized for sharing files in other containers even after exiting from the original container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a data colume container: see "[Creating and mounting a data volume container](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container)"

```
$ docker create -v /dbdata --name dbdata training/postgres /bin/true
$ docker run -d --volumes-from dbdata --name db1 training/postgres
$ docker run -d --volumes-from dbdata --name db2 training/postgres
```

Here, even if the container `db1` exits, `db2` has still access to the shared voume `dbdata`.

`dbdata` is a data volume container that you don't "run" (there is no process running in it, only a shared volume of data); you "create" it only. (and you don't "exit" it either, since you never ran it)

Comment: Though i exit from the container the i could utilize that container's mount point in order to run the other container by utilizing that mount point. How is this possible internally?

Comment: @SowndaryaK You do not exit from a data container. You are using the data container mount point in other containers that you run and then later exit. But the data container remains in status "created": it is never "exited".

Comment: root@ubuntu:/# docker run -v /tmp:/tmp -ti ubuntu /bin/bash 
root@7eb6188873f9:/# cd /tmp
root@7eb6188873f9:/tmp# ls
VMwareDnD  config-err-gnSLwW  pp.txt  s.txt  unity_support_test.0  vmware-root  vmware-sowndarya
root@7eb6188873f9:/tmp# exit
exit
root@ubuntu:/# docker run --volumes-from=7eb6188873f9 -ti ubuntu /bin/bash
root@b7e71c8c7df9:/# cd /tmp
root@b7e71c8c7df9:/tmp# ls
VMwareDnD  config-err-gnSLwW  pp.txt  s.txt  unity_support_test.0  vmware-root  vmware-sowndarya

Comment: @SowndaryaK If you `docker run` a container (declaring a volume) and then exit, that volume is gone with the container. You need to `docker create`, not `docker run`. See my answer where the first command is a `docker create`.

Comment: Yaeh,i have seen but the thing i am getting confussed is y i am still able to utilize that mount point?

Comment: @SowndaryaK because the data volume container (that you have created) is never removed. You can reuse it in other container with `docker run --volumes-from=xxx`

Comment: Thank you VonC .it has helped me a lot

Comment: @SowndaryaK You are welcome. Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote.

Comment: This may seems to  be silly question..sorry for that, where exactly files of docker mount namespace mounts the filesystem in the host ?

Comment: @SowndaryaK most of the docker-related files and filesystem mounted/managed in container are in `/var/lib/docker`